# Why was a moved question deleted? Moderator to whom deletion is attributed claims they didn't do it

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, deleted-questions, moderators

A [question on archive.is on Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135222/why-does-1-1-1-1-not-resolve-archive-is) appears to have been deleted, and deletion is attributed to a moderator,  *deleted by Sathyajith Bhat♦ 12 hours ago* , however, [they claim that they didn't do it](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/why-was-archive-is-question-deleted#comment4838_4714) (however, they did previously (unsuccessfully) tried migrating it to another site in the network where they're also a moderator, but migration was rejected by another moderator, it was then on hold on webapps, and then the hold was removed, which was supposed to have been the end of it).

Can someone explain what's going on here?

And restore the question that clearly wasn't meant to have been deleted, was a HNQ, and has 75 votes on the question, plus 74 votes on the top answer, and 56 on second answer; and 19 on third?  There's a lot of links to this question, too, and now they're all broken, making SE look like a community hostile to a popular question ontopic for the site it was on.

Comment: For visitors and users: This is the migrated question, currently on hold, on SuperUser [Why does 1.1.1.1 not resolve archive.is?](https://superuser.com/questions/1489516/why-does-1-1-1-1-not-resolve-archive-is)

Comment: It could have been an accidental click on the delete link. Usually one notices that and corrects the action, but if one is distracted it may go unnoticed. I've had similar things happen to me.

Comment: This has happened before a _long_ time ago when reverse migrations were causing all kinds of problems but hasn't come up again in years. Going to try to figure out what might have happened.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I checked the logs on this to make sure, and did a bit of experimentation to see if I could reproduce.

The moderator who deleted this was handling flags from the mod dashboard (the post you reference had a pending flag at the time). They'd expanded a preview on a previous post and then deleted it, after which they deleted both the question and another unrelated comment within 1 second.

Items on the mod dashboard shift in position as flags are handled; this is reasonably predictable for most flagged items, but when a preview is expanded (to allow a moderator to view the whole post) the vertical size expands considerably and so the resulting shift when it is removed becomes much less predictable. An errant double-tap or mis-aimed click could easily explain what we saw here.

I was unable to reproduce this by handling flags in a similar manner, provided I was slow and deliberate in what I clicked.

I've undeleted the question.