# What does "deleted" / "undeleted" mean in a question about DNS on Web Applications? Is this related to a migration rejection?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[Why does 1.1.1.1 not resolve archive.is?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135222/88163) was migrated to Super User but then it was returned to Web Applications. Then it shows that it was "deleted" by a diamond moderator but later was undeleted by a now-former employee.

I assume that the question was migrated for a second time but the migration was rejected because the diamond moderator mentioned that he didn't know why the question history shows that he deleted the question.

While the question [was discussed](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4703/88163) on Meta Web Applications there wasn't any explanation of the last "undeletion".

[image]

This is the current body of the referred question

> When I try to access http://archive.is/ with DNS through `1.1.1.1`, it doesn't work.  Why?
>
> ```
> % dig +nocmd +nocomments @one.one.one.one archive.is
> ;archive.is.                    IN      A
> archive.is.             49050   IN      A       127.0.0.3
> ;; Query time: 139 msec
> ;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
> ;; WHEN: Thu Oct  3 17:12:50 2019
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
>
> %
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### There wasn't any explanation of the last "undeletion".

> Per mod making a comment on this very meta question above, the
> original was deleted by mistake yesterday:
>
> > I didn't delete the question - not sure why it's attributed to me. I've asked the question in the mod chat and sent an email to
> > developers to check in on this. – Sathyajith Bhat♦ 16 hours ago
>
> It has since been restored earlier today.
>
> [Hopefully, this is the end of the saga.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334793/221016)

Source [Why was archive.is question deleted?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4718/80183), answer by [cnst](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35808/cnst)

And this is what the (former) developer, Shog9 said:

> I checked the logs on this to make sure, and did a bit of
> experimentation to see if I could reproduce.
>
> The moderator who deleted this was handling flags from the mod
> dashboard (the post you reference had a pending flag at the time).
> They'd expanded a preview on a previous post and then deleted it,
> after which they deleted both the question and another unrelated
> comment within 1 second.
>
> Items on the mod dashboard shift in position as flags are handled;
> this is reasonably predictable for most flagged items, but when a
> preview is expanded (to allow a moderator to view the whole post) the
> vertical size expands considerably and so the resulting shift when it
> is removed becomes much less predictable. An errant double-tap or
> mis-aimed click could easily explain what we saw here.
>
> I was unable to reproduce this by handling flags in a similar manner,
> provided I was slow and deliberate in what I clicked.
>
> I've undeleted the question.

Source [Why was a moved question deleted? Moderator to whom deletion is attributed claims they didn't do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334824/267099), answer by [Shog9](http://%5BWhy%20was%20a%20moved%20question%20deleted?%20Moderator%20to%20whom%20deletion%20is%20attributed%20claims%20they%20didn%27t%20do%20it%5D(https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9))

Comment: So, this question is actually a duplicate of last linked question :)

Comment: @rubin, I guess, but this answer has all of the pieces in one place :) And I'm trying to get my 10K ...